# Difference between [definition] and [terminology]

Tags: discussion, tagging

What is the difference between the tags [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) and [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition)?

At the moment, there are [678 questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) with the [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag, and [278 questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) with the [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) tag, and only [31 questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology+definition) with both, so there seems to be perceived difference.

I'd like to point out that there was a different question (I think the most recent incarnation of this question, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/825/how-should-we-handle-tags-terminology-notation-definition, that was raised on meta two years ago. But as I read through, I thought there was a focus on keeping [notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notation) separated from the others (which I agree with - notation is different).

The wiki for [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) says:

> Questions on the usage and meaning of words in mathematics, the names for mathematical entities, and other such questions.

Interestingly, the tags [jargon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jargon) and [etymology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) are tag-synonyms for [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology). I see a big difference between etymology and definitions.

The wiki for [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) is longer, and says:

> Definitions are the core of mathematical precision; they come to answer "what is X" in mathematics. Into this category fit questions regarding equivalence of definitions; clarifications regarding complicated definitions; as well questions with purposed definitions for mathematical notions with requests for improvements or comments.

Perhaps these are clearly different to someone, but when I see something about "the meaning of words in mathematics... and other such questions" compared to looking at "what is 'X' in mathematics", they look about the same to me.

Comment: I am not sure what way to go. (Whether they should be separated or synonyms.) But one type of questions that, in my opinion, fit [tag:terminology] but does not fit [tag:definition] could be something like this: "I am interested in partially ordered set such that for every countable set there is an upper bound. Is there a name of such posets?"

Comment: I have a deja vu (not the file format, although I also have these), didn't you ask this somewhere before? I remember answering you as well.

Comment: I do see a difference between the two: For example: *[Why are rings called rings?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/61497)* or *[where does the term “integral domain” come from?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/45945)* are questions about (origins of) terminology where the definitions themselves are entirely clear. On the other hand the recent *[On the definition of the Hausdorff distance](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/183601/5363)* is a question about details of a specific definition and doesn't take issue with the terminology at all.

Comment: @Asaf Did you mean [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2453/)?

Comment: @Martin: Ah, yes. I didn't write an answer per se, as it seems (although I still retain a memory of writing an answer to this question before...).

Comment: I don't see how this is a different question from «How should we handle tags: [terminology] [notation] [definition]?». In particular, my answer there applies to this question verbatim, no?

Comment: I see the two tags as duals. Terminology is, "what do you call a relation that is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive?" Definitions is, "what's an equivalence relation?"

Answer (score 2):

At least to me, the two texts describe a different meaning. My understanding is as follows:

- [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) is for asking questions about the terms themselves, how they are defined, or conversely if there is an established term corresponding to a concept.
- [definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definitions) on the other hand is for asking about definitions in general, their relations to each other, what a definition is to begin with, and stuff like that.

To make an analogy with visual perception: [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) is about the things you see. [definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definitions) is about the process of seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give what I believe is an example demonstrating the difference between definition and terminology.

Definition. Let $X$ be a nonvoid set and let $\mathfrak{F}(X)$ denote the set of filters on $X$. A preconvergence structure on $X$ is a nonvoid subset $p$ on $\mathfrak{F}(X) \times X$.

Terminology. Let $p$ be a preconvergence structure on $X$. We will write $(\cal{F},x)\in p$ as $\cal{F}\to x$ and read it as "$\cal{F}$ converges to $x$" or "$\cal{F}$ $p$-converges to $x$" or "$\cal{F}$ converges to $x$ in $p$" or "$\cal{F}$ converges to $x$ in $X$", etc.